# python flask jquery get issue

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

What is the mystery of this Web Server issue.

Here is my code its work well on local server, but in the Web Server it's doesn't work:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/flask/templates/table.html",
      type: "get",
      data: {jsdata: $( "#select option:selected" ).text()},
      success: function(response) {
        $("#place_for_suggestions").html(response);

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        // handle error
      }
    });
```

The flask side:

```
@FlaskApp2.route('/flask/templates/table.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def table():

    modid = request.args.get('jsdata')

    print "Hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", modid 
    return render_template('table.html')
```

I try to see any activity in @FlaskApp2.route but I see only silent !

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you see what is the network request sent from the browser and paste the request data here.

Comment: GET http://domen.com/flask/templates/table.html?jsdata=Data%20Air HTTP/1.1
Host: domen.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://domen.com/flask/rest
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=259990281.1969885139.1506122487.1506122487.1506737103.2; __utmz=259990281.1506122487.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

Comment: I have 404 error! But why???

Answer (score 0):

The verbs of the methods=['GET','POST'] are case sensitive when matching your route. So in your .ajax use `method: 'GET'` instead of `type: 'get'`.  On later versions of jquery `type` has been replaced by `method`.

Comment: jQuery ensures the method [is uppercase](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/7037facc2243ec24c2b36b770236c05d300aa513/src/ajax.js#L583) so there’s no difference here.